# One question involving the Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x)=x g(x),$ where $g(x)$ has a continuous derivative for $x > 0$ and $g(a) = 0$ for some $a>0$.

Prove
$$\int_1^a f'(x) \ln(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = -\int_1^a g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$
How can I start this?

Comment: Try integration by parts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By integration by parts we have
$$\int_1^a f'(x) \ln x \, dx=f(a)\ln a-\int_1^a \frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx=ag(a)\ln a-\int_1^a g(x) \, dx=-\int_1^a g(x) \, dx$$